# How do you access secondary calendar Events?

Tags: api, graph, calendar, office365api

This could have been easy, but I am not able to figure out, how do I access events of secondary calendar using Graph API

This line gives me list of available calendars
var calendarList= graphClient.Me.Calendars.Request().GetAsync();

The calendar I want is in index 3.....
But

calendarList[3].Events is null , nor it has methods like Request() or GetAsync()
That is quite strange.

So my question is how do I access events of secondary calendar ?

Any advice ?

Regards